# Redirect unauthorized users asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web, active-directory

I'm working on a simple website in asp.net.
I would like to restric access to the side, so that only users in a specific AD group is allowed. I have done that and it is working fine. But when a user that's not in the AD group tries to access the site, they are getting a login prompt. How do I redirect the unauthorized user to a custom page, instead of they getting the login prompt?

Below is my web.config. The lowest part of the code, is something i tried but did not work.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="DOMAIN\GROUP"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="AccessDenied.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

I have added this to the Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Status.StartsWith("401"))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                Server.Execute("AccessDenied.aspx");
            }
}
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**
I tried some of the posted solutions, but they did not work.
**But I got it working with this code:**

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Response.StatusCode == 401)
        && (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)))
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because  `<allow users="*"/>` means any user is allowed to access , You have to allow a specific group or users .

Comment: Yes, for some reason some of the web.config was not displayed.

Comment: `Propmt` means yellow error page right ??

Comment: have your code solved the issue ? I hope so if not try the answer below .

Comment: Which version of `IIS` you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) or [`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx");
```

**Full example:**

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Status.StartsWith("401"))
  {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
      Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to handle all "Unauthorized" errors:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="401" redirect="Unauthorized.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="Forbidden.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Any 401 (unauthorized) requests will be forwarded to Unauthorized.aspx.

Comment: This does not work, though it should. Microsoft makes interesting decisions in their design sometimes.

Comment: This may not work due to the fact that a '401 Unauthorized' returned by the UrlAuthorizationModule is converted into a '302 Redirect' by FormsAuthenticationModule: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs

Answer (score 1):

I had more success with this:

```
      // This is a workaround for the fact that we are not using MVC and its attributes
      // This is the situation where a user is logged in - but not authorized for this page
      void Application_EndRequest (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
         if (((Response.StatusCode == 302) && (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)))
         {
            try
            {
               string sLoc = Response.Headers ["Location"];
               if (sLoc.Contains ("Login"))
               {
                  Response.ClearContent ();
                  Response.Redirect ("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
               }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<authorization>
 <!--<allow users="*"/>-->This here means allow everyone .
 <allow users="AD"/> -- Add this group to AD domain .  
 <deny users="?"/> --Deny unknown users(Not authenticated)
 <allow roles="Admins"/> --If you have created roles .
```

If you have local group than use `<allow user ="AD">` but you have to register it to AD domain .
`<allow roles ="AD" />` will work only with Domain AD groups not for local groups .

```
 protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender,EventArgs e) 

  { 
     HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
     if (context.Response.Status.Substring(0,3).Equals("401"))
     {
        context.Response.ClearContent();
         //do redirect here 
     } 
  }
```

Comment: `allow user` is for user account names, not AD groups.

Comment: @Nicholas   If you could just check this statement  `If you have local group than use <allow user ="AD"> but you have to register it to AD domain . <allow roles ="AD" /> will work only with Domain AD groups not for local groups .` This statement might be confusing and leading readers in another direction I might change it with better words till then thanks for pointing out but I am not saying a`allow user is for Active Directory `.

Comment: If you use `allow roles` and set the role manager to `WindowsTokenRoleProvider` it will detect both local computer groups and domain security groups if the server is a member of the domain. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx